# Como retirar todas as sequências de uma string

Tags: php

Tenho a string :

```
$textMostraMarcado = '3 3 1 6 8 6 8 <b>1 1 1 </b>2 4 2 7 5 <b>4 4 4 4 </b>9 <b>8 8 8 </b>7'
```

Gostaria de obter o resultado:

```
<b>1 1 1 </b>
<b>4 4 4 4 </b>
<b>8 8 8 </b>
```

Isto é, obter os valores que estão entre as tags `<b></b>`.

Comment: Tem como você descrever em palavras o que seria esse resultado? Você deseja pegar o conteúdo que está entre as tags `<b></b>`?

Comment: Exatamente isso, obter as sequencias em negrito. Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta utilizar expressões com a função [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php):

1. O primeiro parâmetro da função será a expressão regular: `/<b>.*?<\/b>/`;
2. O segundo parâmetro será o texto de onde será extraído as informações;
3. O terceiro parâmetro será a lista de informações extraídas;

Por exemplo:

```
if (preg_match_all("/<b>.*?<\/b>/", $textMostraMarcado, $matches))
{
  print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

A saída será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <b>1 1 1 </b>
    [1] => <b>4 4 4 4 </b>
    [2] => <b>8 8 8 </b>
)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/yEyYzD).